# Video.js player not using expected options

Tags: javascript, html, caching, video.js

I have a simple HTML page, with a small JS snippet to act as a playlist, and it worked fine.

I added Video.js and there is a problem, if I close the page and come back again - sometimes! - it will not load the player and the videos would appear smaller or bigger meaning it will not load the aspect ratio in the Video.js settings! (Still the JS snippet in the main page that acts like a playlist controller works fine) so that if I click on any video the player will change to that video, but Video.js won't work, only the first frame appears, and the size is inaccurate (meaning that Video.js didn't work), and I should REFRESH every time this happens!..
I tried `player.dispose()` at the end of my main page, didn't work.. I tried to get rid of caching by this line at the head (`<script>document.write('<script src="vid.js?dev=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '"\><\/script>');</script>`) and didn't work as well :(..

here's my code for your reference, hoping you'd find a solution for me...
**note: the code works fine on localhost (MAMP) with only adding defer to the script tag of vid.js .. but on online host it still has the problem..

````
<head>
// HTML HEADER and things! 
<!-- style for the page -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="tphysics.css">
    
    <!-- style CDN for vjs  -->
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.17.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main-video">
      <div class="video">
    <video
    id="vid"
    class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered"
    max-width="100%"
    height="auto"
    oncontextmenu="return false;"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="lessons/test3.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
    </div>
  </div>

      <!-- here comes the video list  -->

      <div class="video-list">
        <div class="vid active">
            <video src="lessons/test3.mp4" muted></video>
            <h3 class="title">01. heres the video title</h3>
        </div>
          <div class="vid">
            <video src="lessons/test2.mp4" muted poster="./tphysics2.jpg"></video>
            <h3 class="title">02. heres the video title</h3>
        </div> 
        
    </div>

</div>


<!-- videoJS CDN -->
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.17.0/video.min.js"></script>
     
    <!-- JavaScript for the vjs library  -->
    <script src="vid.js" defer ></script>

<!-- JavaScript for the playlist -->
<script >
  let listVideo = document.querySelectorAll('.video-list .vid');
  let mainVideo = document.querySelector('.main-video video');
  let title = document.querySelector('.main-video .title');
  
  listVideo.forEach(video =>{
    video.onclick = () =>{
      listVideo.forEach(vid => vid.classList.remove('active'));  
      video.classList.add('active');
      if(video.classList.contains('active')){
        let src = video.children[0].getAttribute('src');
        mainVideo.src = src;
        let text = video.children[1].innerHTML;
        title.innerHTML = text;    
      };
      
    };
  });

  </script>
</body>
</html>```


*** Note: I added (defer) to the vid.js file so that it runs after the whole html is loaded and that it detects the Video element (according to what I read).. 

*** the vid.js file code is here ..

 
```var player = videojs('vid',{
    autoplay: true,
    controls: true,
    poster: './tphysics2.jpg',
    loop: ture,
    aspectRatio: '16:9',
    preload: true, //the browser chooses the best action    
    // fill: true, //this is to fill the container!
    // fluid: true,
    playbackRates: [0.25, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
    responsive: true, //https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-layout.html
    plugins: {

    }

});```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `data-setup="{}"`. You've a race condition where the player is set up by video.js automatically on document load because of that attribute, with no options, or by your vid.js setting it up with your options.